# For a purpose of a clinical study, what is considered to be a cardiovascular death?

Tags: clinical-study

In the [FOURIER study](http://www.nejm.org/doi/pdf/10.1056/NEJMoa1615664) (to lower cholesterol with PCSK9), there is a significant reduction in different types of cardiovascular events (MI and Stroke) in the treatment group and yet the total cardiovascular mortality has not decreased compared to placebo (page 6 of pdf). What kind of other conditions/diagnoses could account for the extra deaths in the treatment group from 'Cardiovascular death' that compensates for MI and stroke?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cardiovascular death is a general term meaning death caused by anything involving the heart or blood vessels. I can't find and don't think there exists a formal definition. Aside from stroke and MI, the major examples would be:

- [Sudden cardiac arrest](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardiac_arrest)
- [Pulmonary embolism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pulmonary_embolism)
- [Congestive heart failure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heart_failure)
- [Lethal arrhythmias](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardiac_arrhythmia)
- [Aortic dissection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aortic_dissection)
- [Myocardial rupture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Myocardial_rupture)
- [Cardiac tamponade](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardiac_tamponade)

Comment: thanks, that's roughly the list I was looking for (possibly in addition to the breakdown for this specific study, but I realize that might be hard without having full study data ...).

Comment: @Curios Yeah, having the study's working definition would be the best. I only skimmed the paper so I could have missed it, but I didn't see them define it, which they really should have.